# Method to prevent Google from viewing the addition of many external links at once negatively: nofollow VS iframe VS javascript?

Tags: seo, javascript, links, nofollow, iframe

I need to add blocks to the main content of a site.

Those blocks contain multiple (between 15-30) links to **different** websites (with **related content**).

I currently do have good SEO and before I develop the structure I would like to know what practice is better:

- Create an iframe containing the linked sites.
- Add the nofollow attribute.
- Add a JS onclick listener that changes the window.location.

But JS option is supposed to have the same effect as a normal link, according to this ("Google parses JS" - https://searchengineland.com/know-google-sees-javascript-links-dont-277057).

What option is better for SEO and why? Can you think of a fourth and even better option? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I say none of the above if you have full editorial control of those links.

Comment: Why do anything? Do you not _trust_ these links? Just have normal links (the "forth" option).

Comment: @JohnConde Attaching external ressources instead of copying them or reproducing them with new words. I read that Google will consider it as "spam" if a site has too many links. It takes time and effort to produce the main content, and I don't want to make a counterproductive move by including many external ressources.

Comment: Define "too many". I also suspect if that is true it is more relevant to spammy directories than quality content sites. If those links are relevant to your content and site and are trusted sites (i.e. not spammy or otherwise low quality) you shouldn't do anything to the links to those resources.

Comment: why do you mean, your clickouts are bad? There are cases, where clickouts are indeed bad, but in other cases clickouts don't make any negative influence...